# Cardinal Orderings: What is he even asking for?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

Consider the following exercise.

> Show that for any set $S$ we have $S \preccurlyeq {}^S2$, but $S \not\approx {}^S2$. (This should be done directly, without use of
> $\mathscr{P}S$ or cardinal numbers. If $F: S \rightarrow {}^S2$, then
> define $g(x) = 1 - F(x)(x)$.)

I'm confused. What type of proof is he even asking for? Does he just want me to create an explicit injection from S into ${}^S2$ (the word "directly" confuses me)? If so, how do I generate such a function? I was thinking maybe something like $F(a) = \langle a, 0 \rangle \cup f[\![S - a]\!]$ for any function $f \in {}^S2$? But is this even a valid way of defining a function? Also, why does he mention $g(x) = 1 - F(x)(x)$? Why does it matter and where did $g$ even come from? This is Exercise 6.16 from Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory* by the way, in case any of you want to look for yourself which exercise I'm referencing. I'm probably missing something.

Note: $f[\![x]\!]$ is the image of $x$ under $f$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right ideas.

Yes, you have to construct an injection from $S$ into ${}^S 2$. Of course, one approach would be to take the obvious injection from $S$ into $\mathcal{P}(S)$ by sending $x \in S$ to $\{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(S)$. Then compose this with the bijection $\mathcal{P}(S) \approx {}^S 2$. However, the exercise asks to do it "directly", so that means that they want you to give an explicit description of the injection from $S$ into ${}^S 2$.

**Hint:** can you use the injection I described before (so $x \mapsto \{x\}$, composed with $\mathcal{P}(S) \approx {}^S 2$) to construct an explicit injection from $S$ into ${}^S 2$?

There is a second part to the exercise. Namely to show that $S \not \approx {}^S 2$. This is where the hint is useful. Suppose for a contradiction that $S \approx {}^S 2$. Then let $F: 2 \to {}^S 2$ be a bijection and use the hint to define $g(x) = 1 - F(x)(x)$. So $g$ is a function from $S$ to $2$, that is $g \in {}^S 2$. Can you use this to find the contradiction?

Comment: Thank you! You really helped clarify what the question was asking for. Sadly, it's almost 4AM where I'm at and I'm utterly exhausted, so I'll have to attempt a solution with your hints and clarifications after I wake up, but I just wanted you to know that your explanation was really helpful :)

Comment: @mijucik No worries, glad to be able to help. Good luck solving it tomorrow!

Comment: I couldn't sleep so I attempted the first part of the exercise. Would the function $F(x)$ mapping to the corresponding function $f: S \rightarrow 2$ such that $
f(x') = 
\begin{cases}
 1 & \text{if } x' \in S - \{x\}\\ 
 0 & \text{if } x' = x
\end{cases}
$ work as a suitable injection?

Comment: @mijucik Yes, that's right!

Comment: And would the contradiction be that for any function $f$ in $\text{ran}F$, there would always be a function $g$ in ${}^S2$ such that the value of $g$ is always different than $f$, thus implying that $F$ cannot be surjective?

Comment: @mijucik Yes, that's the idea for that part. Although you should be careful about the phrasing: $g$ should not depend on $f$. We construct $g$ first, and then show for all $f$ in the range of $F$ that $g$ and $f$are different.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much for your help :)